# php extract year/month/day/hour/minute/seconds from a date

Tags: php, date, extract

if i have a date and i want to extract the year, the month, etc in PHP5, how should i proceed?

if i do

```
 $y = date('Y',$sale->end);
```

it doesn't work...

Comment: what is $sale->end? Function date() works with unix timestamps only. So if it's a string like '2011-03-12' you have to convert it to timestamped value.

Comment: Are you asking which options to pass to `date`? That's all given in the PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `$sale->end` is a valid datestamp, pass it through `strtotime()` like so:

```
$y = date('Y', strtotime($sale->end));
```

Answer (score 11):

As jnpcl indicated, if `$sale->end` holds a valid datestamp you can do the following:

```
list($year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$second)=explode('-',date('Y-m-d-h-i-s',strtotime($sale->end)));
```